# Search functionality on form not working properly

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a form `Main` with a subform `Issue` on it.  To implement search functionality on `Main` so that users can search for records in `Issue` that have a given substring, `Main` has a text box `keyword` and a submit button `SubmitBtn`.  Here is the VBA code I am using to try to make this work:

```
Private Sub SubmitBtn_Click()   
 Dim keyword As String
 Dim recordSourceSql As String

 keyword = Nz(Me.keyword.value)
 recordSourceSql = "select * from [Issue] where [Details] like " & quoteWrap(keyword)  
 Me.Issue.Form.RecordSource = recordSourceSql
 Me.Issue.Form.Requery
End Sub

Private Function quoteWrap(value As String) As String
 quoteWrap = "'*" & value & "*' "
End Function
```

The problem is that after this line:

```
Me.Issue.Form.RecordSource = recordSourceSql
```

there is only one record showing in `Issue`--it's the first record in the original recordset, when there should be at least 20 records showing with the value of `keyword` that I tested.  Once this occurs, the `Me.Issue.Form.Requery` call does not change the contents of `Issue`.

I know that the correct `recordSourceSQL` is being created, because when I put in, e.g., "data" for `keyword`, I get this string for `recordSourceSQL`:

```
select * from [Issue] where [Details] like '*data*'
```

and when I create a query in Access and set this as the SQL, I get all the correct results returned.

What's wrong with this code to search the subform according to the given criteria?

UPDATE: I was able to get this to work by setting `Me.Issue.Form.Filter` to the WHERE clause in `recordSourceSql`.  I don't understand why `.Filter` works but changing `.RecordSource` doesn't.

UPDATE 2: The `.Filter` solution is not working either.  I've described this issue in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23506039/619177).

Comment: Does adding `Me.Issue.Form.Refresh` after your `Requery` work?

Comment: @enderland, no, same results.  Again, the contents of the form are already changing before the `Requery` is even called.

Comment: Also - how does this even run? This line is not valid for VBA code `recordSourceSql = "select * from [Issue] where "[Details] like " & quoteWrap(keyword)` -- it has mismatched `"`. I'm not sure how that works, you have an extra in from of [Details].

Comment: @enderland, sorry, that was a typo.  I'll remove the " from in front of [Details].

Comment: What is your actual code you are running? Didn't you copy paste this? When are you getting the value of `recordSourceSQL`? Try adding a debug statement immediately after you create it. I also add a `;` to the end of my SQL statements in Access for forms and don't have a trailing space, not sure if this makes a difference.

Comment: not sure if it matters but have you tried `select Issue.* From Issue ...` Also is the Issue Form continuous? If not it will only Show 1 record at a time you would need navigation to get to the other "Issues".

Comment: Is your subform bound in some way to the parent form? are the records that are not shown filtered out because of a binding you have going?

Comment: @Brad, no, there's no binding between `Issue` and `Main`.  I noted in an update that setting the form's `Filter` property works.

Comment: When you changed the record source was there also a filter that stayed in place?

Comment: @Brad, the record source wasn't filtered until I set the filter in VBA.

Comment: Your code should work.  It is difficult to diagnose without seeing all your subform code.  Is there code behind your subform, such as in the load or current events that is overriding the recordsource you are setting in the parent form?  Or, sometimes when you save a form in datasheet mode, you can accidentally save a filter criteria in there, so that might be why your filter criteria works -- because it's overriding what was saved in the subform?

Comment: @pghcpa,There is no filtering code in the load event.  And there are no filters saved in the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a sample, copied your code and was able to replicate your problem and solve it.

If your subform was unbound (i.e., recordsource was empty) and the primary key of your main table and Issue table had the same field name (e.g., both were named "ID", etc.) and you did not link any parent or child fields, then it will only work if you specifically name each field like this:

```
recordSourceSql = "SELECT Issue.IssueID, Issue.Details FROM Issue WHERE Issue.Details Like '*Data*'"
```

You are correct!  Wildcards in the select don't work in this scenario, including Select Issue.* From Issue.

Alternatively, if you rename the primary key in your Issue table so it is not the same as your main form main table, then the wildcards work as you would expect.  When I made this change your exact code worked:

```
recordSourceSql = "SELECT * FROM Issue WHERE Details Like " & quoteWrap(Keyword)
```

Note the Me.Issue.Form.Requery is not necessary.  Just setting or changing the RecordSource automatically requeries.

It does not seem to matter if the two primary key fields are dragged to the main or subform.  It also doesn't help to make the subform databound but empty with an initial recordsource in the property sheet of "Select * from Issue Where 1=2" (one way to create an empty recordset, but keep the form bound).

I don't know if this is an MS-Access quirk or something intentional.  It seems to me that I must have come across this scenario many times (primary key was "ID", subform unbound, no child fields linked) but I don't recall coming across this limitation.  Maybe I didn't use a wildcard.  When I googled, I didn't find this reported by others but no doubt some MS-Access expert out there will know the reason.

Hope this helps.